# addition in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, addition

I recently was working on a checkout system based in flex 3 and had an order total that didn't make sense to me. I was adding a subtotal, shipping cost, and tax. All 3 of those values were rounded to 2 decimal places but my answer didn't appear to be rounded at all.

After looking into what was happening I discovered any time you add .95 and .15 instead of getting 1.1 you get 1.09999999 repeating. Starting with variations of that doesn't make a difference, in my original case it was (17.95 + 5 + 1.15). Flex gave me 24.09999.

Is there a reason for this? I can just round the final number again and get the correct result but it seems odd that such basic arithmetic would be wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You're probably better off just using [toPrecision()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#toPrecision()) on Number.  This is pretty much a problem on most languages that weren't specifically designed for number crunching, and has to do with how the number is stored on the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way computers handle floating point numbers, they often times will be very close to, but not exactly the same value you input.  The number has to fit in a fixed number of bits, so some resolution is lost for the trade off of space. This is a limitation of computers, not flex.

A fairly simple explanation
http://joshblog.net/2007/01/30/flash-floating-point-number-errors/

A much more in depth explanation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point